# How to use C library from Haskell?

Tags: c, haskell, interop, ffi

I am trying to call a C function from Haskell using the FFI and I keep getting this error :

> ghc.exe: ^^ Could not load 'getSize', dependency unresolved. See top
>   entry above.
>
> main: ByteCodeLink: can't find label During interactive linking, GHCi
>   couldn't find the following symbol:   getSize This may be due to you
>   not asking GHCi to load extra object files, archives or DLLs needed by
>   your current session.  Restart GHCi, specifying the missing library
>   using the -L/path/to/object/dir and -lmissinglibname flags, or simply
>   by naming the relevant files on the GHCi command line. Alternatively,
>   this link failure might indicate a bug in GHCi. If you suspect the
>   latter, please send a bug report to:
>   glasgow-haskell-bugs@haskell.org

I am using the `stdio.h` library in my C library:

**C library**

```c
// lib.h
#include <stdio.h>

double getSize() {
    double size = 0;
    scanf("$f", &size);
    return size;
}
```

**FFI module**

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Ffi where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types

foreign import ccall "lib.h getSize" c_size :: IO Double
```

**Main**

```hs
module Main where
import Ffi

main :: IO ()
main = do a <- getLine
          b <- c_size
          print $ "got from C: " ++ show b
```

**Running script**

```hs
gcc -o lib -lib.h
runghc main
```

**P.S.** Could this be because I somehow have to specify the dependency `stdio.h` somewhere else too?

Comment: Why is there code in an `.h` file? What commands are you using to compile the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, there are several things to do here:

- Rename "lib.h" to "lib.c".  It's a C source file (containing code), not a C header file.
- Ideally, add a separate "lib.h" header file with the prototype for `getSize`.
- Fix the bug in "lib.c".  You want "%lf" in place of "$f" to read in a double.
- Compile the program with `ghc` instead of running it with `runghc`.  A single `ghc` command can compile and link both Haskell modules and C code.

In other words, your files should look like:

```c
// lib.c
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
double getSize() {
    double size = 0;
    scanf("%lf", &size);
    return size;
}
```

```c
// lib.h
double getSize(void);
```

```hs
-- Ffi.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Ffi where
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
foreign import ccall "lib.h getSize" c_size :: IO Double
```

```hs
-- Main.hs
module Main where
import Ffi
main :: IO ()
main = do a <- getLine
          b <- c_size
          print $ "got from C: " ++ show b
```

and you should compile it with:

```
$ ghc Main.hs lib.c
[1 of 2] Compiling Ffi              ( Ffi.hs, Ffi.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
```

Then you can run it, supply a line for the Haskell `getLine` and a second line for the C `scanf`, and it should work fine:

```
$ ./Main
hello world!!   -- line for Haskell
135.0           -- line for C
"got from C: 135.0"
```

Comment: I'd also suggest to write a proper header c file `lib.h` with the prototype. It is unusual to `foreign import` a `.c` file.

Comment: Fair enough.  I've added "lib.h" to the example.